# Why plays Objective-C AVFoundation Video Player a MP4 file format only in Simulator and not on real device?

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, mp4, mov

I need to build my own video player with AVFoundation and came way far. But the player only plays the .mp4-file in simulator. No video shows up if I run the app on a device. But if I use a .mov-file all is working fine.
Also when I play the video file inside an MPMoviePLayer the file shows up and plays well.

the .mp4-file uses

AVC Coding, 2.048 x 1.536
AAC, 48000 Hz, Stereo (L R)

The audio track is empty.

Does anybody know why? [Here is some sample code.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/AVFoundationVideoPLayer.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `introCycle_sml.mp4` is of 2048x1536 pixels and data rate is 3.71 Mbits/s, while iOS supports MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels.

Comment: hm - ok. sounds like it could be the reason. thnx! but I need to have a crisp video on retina iPad3. what is the best solution here?

Comment: I suggest to recompress video to H.264 1080p - the max allowed resolution for iPad3.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Even New iPad able to play h264 1080p video, but `MPMoviePlayerController` supports "H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps".